# Laravel Eloquent many to many relationship with translation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with a many to many relationship and the translations of the terms.
I have 4 tables:

```
products
    - id, price, whatever
products_lang
    - id, product_id, lang, product_name
accessori
    - id, active
accessori_lang
    - id, accessori_id, lang, accessori_name
```

I'm trying to assign accessories to products with an intermediate table named:

```
accessori_products
```

this is the model for Product:

```
class Product extends Model {

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function productsLang () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductLng', 'products_id')->where('lang','=',App::getLocale());
    }

    public function productsLangAll() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductLng', 'products_id');
    }

    public function accessori() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Accessori', 'accessori_products');
    }
}
```

this is the model for productLng:

```
class ProductLng extends Model {

    protected $table = 'products_lng';

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'products_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then I have the model for Accessori:

```
class Accessori extends Model {

    protected $table = 'accessori';

    public function accessoriLang() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AccessoriLng')->where('lang','=',App::getLocale());
    }

    public function accessoriLangAll() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AccessoriLng');
    }

    public function accessoriProducts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'accessori_products', 'accessori_id', 'products_id');
    }
}
```

And the model for AccessoriLng:

```
class accessoriLng extends Model {

    protected $table = 'accessori_lng';

    public function accessori() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Accessori', 'accessori_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

the last model is for the relationship between the two tables above:

```
class ProductAccessori extends Model {

    protected $table = 'accessori_products';

    public function accessoriProducts() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'accessori_id', 'products_id');
    }

}
```

I'm trying to get the accessories of each product and to get also the translation but I'm having a lot of problem with this. 
It's my first time with a many to many relation with translations too.
Can anyone put me on the right direction?

Comment: what lang you try to get ? product_lang, accessori_lang, or both ?

Comment: @punk73 accessori_lang

Comment: You don't need to make a model for many-to-many intermediate table (in your case that is ```ProductAccessori ``` model).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

controller

```
$products = Product::has('accessori')->with([
  'productsLang ',
  'accessori' => function ($accessori){
      $accessori->with([
        'accessoriLang'
      ]);
   }
])->get();

return $products;
```

you'll get products with accessori that has accessoriLang.